# LINQ: .Select infinite loop

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting what appears to be an infinite loop in either LINQ or somehow JQuery. **It keeps calling the Controller Method over and over.**
Here's my controller method:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // TODO: decide what properties determine a need for User Action (the 'where(s)')
        var viewModel = new PriorityTasksViewModel
        {
            BayOptions = _bayOptionRepository.GetBayOptions()
                .Where(x => x.IsActive && !x.SiteVisibilityFlagsOverride).ToList()
                .Select(x => new PriorityTasksBayOptionsViewModel() 
                {
                    BayGuid = x.BayGUID, 
                    BayNumber = x.BayNumber, 
                    PropertyId = x.PropertyId
                })
                .ToList(),
            Properties = _propertyRepository.GetProperties()
                .Where(x => !x.SiteVisibilityFlagsOverride).ToList()
                .Select(x => new PriorityTasksPropertiesViewModel() 
                {
                    PropertyId = x.PropertyId, 
                    PropertyName = x.Name
                })
                .ToList()
        };
        return View("_PriorityTasks", viewModel);
    }
```

If I put a breakpoint in the view, I verify it's looping. What am I missing in my LINQ? I put .ToList() in there to force loading but...
View:

```
<h6>Properties</h6>

<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        Name
    </th>       
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model.Properties) {
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="@(Url.Action("Edit", "Property"))">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PropertyName)</a>
    </td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

And the JQuery at the bottom of the _Layout:(it has to show on teh menu of layout)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#PriorityTasks').load('@Url.Action("Index", "PriorityTask")');
})
```

Comment: What you mean infinite loop? The `@foreach` on the view? If you can breakpoint you can know how many items are there int `Model.Properties

Comment: no, I mean it keeps calling the controller method over and over and thus the view. not sure if it's the JQuery doing it or what.

Comment: well my guess is the jquery... but you dont show what is `$('#PriorityTasks')`

Comment: Sorry, "PriorityTasks' is a blank empty div on the _layout

Comment: there's nothing wrong with your linq. if the controller is being called repeatedly it's because there are multiple requests being sent to it. check your javascript

Comment: there's a jQuery `load()` at the bottom of the layout? is the `View()` you're returning part of that layout?

Comment: Your jQuery loads the contents of the Index view, as soon as *any* view that uses `_Layout` finishes loading - an infinite recursion actually. LINQ has nothing to do with this, it's about querying databases or collections

Comment: Maybe you need return a partial view instead.

Comment: bingo, return a PartialView, my bad. thanks all!

Comment: It needs to be `$('#PriorityTasks').load('@Url.Action("Index", "PriorityTask")');` not `@Html.Action()` - `Url.Action()` generates a url, but `Html.Action()` calls your `Index()` method which generates a view containing `@Html.Action()` which in turn calls `Index()` again which generates a view containing `@Html.Action()` which in turn calls `Index()` and so on and so on, creating an endless loop

Comment: Thanks Stephen I caught that after I posted the question. all I had to do after that was change it to 'Return PartialView'.

Comment: WIsh I could mark a comment as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need return a partial view instead

```
return PartialView("_PriorityTasks", viewModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want keep a layout you could use a partial view.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Images(int? page)
{
    int pageNumber = page ?? 1;
    page = page ?? 1;
    var images = db.image.AsQueryable().OrderBy(x => x.name);

    var onePageOfImages = images.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
    ViewBag.onePageOfImages = onePageOfImages;

    return (page == 0)
        ? PartialView()
        : (ActionResult)PartialView("_ImageList");
}
```

Images.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Image List";
}
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;

@Styles.Render("~/Content/PagedList.css")

<h2>Image List</h2>

@DateTime.Now.ToString()

<div id="unobtrusive">
    @Html.Partial("_ImageList")
</div>
```

and _ImageList

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
```

Comment: Thanks but, the answer was to change it to 'Return PartialView' instead of 'Return view' in the above comments

Comment: Yes, i made that comment. And also my sample here is with `return PartialView` because I also have a similar issue once. Still don't know why you didnt accept my answer as the correct answer.

Comment: Because it's not the right answer, man. I asked why it was reloading, not how to paginate it. And it is already a partial view. Thanks anyway.

Comment: copy/paste your comment into an answer, I'll check it off.

Comment: I know you didnt need pagination, but that is the example i have at hand . Good you make work :)